# getting error of pulling json from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting error saying: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error."`

whether I do

```js
url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/v3/uvi/20,77/current.json?appid=c0d8761ca979157a45651a5c7f12a6be';
function getJSONP(url, success) {

    var ud = '_' + +new Date,
        script = document.createElement('script'),
        head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] 
               || document.documentElement;

    window[ud] = function(data) {
        head.removeChild(script);
        success && success(data);
    };

    script.src = url.replace('callback=?', 'callback=' + ud);
    head.appendChild(script);

}

getJSONP(url, function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html><body>
```

or if I do :

```js
url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/v3/uvi/20,77/current.json?appid=c0d8761ca979157a45651a5c7f12a6be';

function CallURL() {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    async: false,
    success: function(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
      JsonpCallback(msg);
    },
    error: function() {
      // ErrorFunction();
      // break ;
    }
  });
}

function JsonpCallback(json) {
  alert(json);
  //document.getElementById('summary').innerHTML = json.result;
}

CallURL();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This url doesn't return JSONP, it's return JSON:

```
{"time":"2017-02-25T12:00:00Z","location":{"latitude":18.75,"longitude":76.75},"data":10.8}
```

OpeanWeather API support JSONP only for few calls, like http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&callback=test&appid=c0d8761ca979157a45651a5c7f12a6be, other call support only JSON, XML or HTML (see https://openweathermap.org/current for details).

So use **json** in ajax type call:

```js
url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/v3/uvi/20,77/current.json?appid=c0d8761ca979157a45651a5c7f12a6be';

function CallURL() {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
    },
    error: function() {
      // ErrorFunction();
      // break ;
    }
  });
}

CallURL();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```